# Can one downgrade a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra from Android 14 to Android 13?

Tags: downgrade, android-13, android-14, samsung-galaxy-s-23

I have a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra running Android 13. I am considering upgrading it to Android 14. Can one downgrade a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra from Android 14 to Android 13?

I found https://flash.android.com/ but Samsung Galaxy is not listed amongst their supported devices.

Comment: I would not recommend downgrading at all here's why.
https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/verifiedboot

Answer (score 0):

One can use Samsung's [Odin (firmware flashing software)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin_(firmware_flashing_software)) to  downgrade a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra from Android 14 to Android 13 (by flashing the device to Android 13, which means all data/settings will be lost):

> Although none of the publicly available downloads are authorized by [Samsung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung) itself, [XDA-Developers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XDA-Developers) consider the files offered on their Forum ([Patched Odin v3 3.13.1 for windows](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/patched-odin-3-13-1.3762572/)) ([Odin v4 1.2.1 for linux](https://xdaforums.com/t/official-samsung-odin-v4-1-2-1-dc05e3ea-for-linux.4453423/)) the safest option.

Alternatively, one may use [Heimdall](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Odin_(firmware_flashing_software)&oldid=1183326250#Heimdall) (open-source).

Thanks [Reddit](https://redd.it/17q2nrc) for pointing me to Odin.

Comment: Just want to confirm if this has been tested and worked? Because Android has downgrade protection depending on the bootloader version.

Comment: @AndrewT. Good point, I haven't tested and I haven't read yet anyone who did test it.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a couple of videos saying it's possible but I don't think it works on all devices, it could be for some specific versions of bootloader.
I tried downgrading mine from Android 14 (One-UI 6.0) to Android 13 (One-UI 5.1) but failed when trying to flash with Odin.
I was only able to flash the latest version and not old versions.
My Samsung is S23 Ultra (SM-S918B)

Error encounter: `sw rev check fail abl fused 3 binary 1`